# Calculating the difference between two columns based on a match on two columns and displaying that result

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a question regarding find matching values between two columns, returning the values adjcent to those column and then working ou the difference. The problem is, I can't use a Vlookup because the data that I am trying to find a match has duplicates. Here is the structure of the table:

```
ITEM | Stock_1 | sellable_1  |  SKU | Stock_2 | sellable_2
 1        0         2           1        0        1
 2        0         9           2        0        2
 1        0         1           2        0        1
```

Now, I basically  want to say where Item and SKU match, return to me the matched values, along with the stock_1, sellable_1 stock_2, sellable_2.

So essentially, ill have this:

```
mathced | stock_1 | sellable_1 | sku | stock_2 | sellable_2
```

Is there a way of doing this on excel?

Please help

Comment: Yes, there are many ways of doing this in Excel.  What have you tried?  `Advanced Filter` is just one of the ways.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I've tried using a vlookup, but realised it wont work because the item and sku column and duplicate values

Comment: And did you try the `Advanced Filter`? That will certainly work on your posted data.

Answer (score 0):

*To use a worksheet formula to compare the data in two columns, follow these steps:
Start Excel.
In a new worksheet, enter the following data (leave column B empty):
A1: 1   B1:     C1: 3
A2: 2   B2:     C2: 5
A3: 3   B3:     C3: 8
A4: 4   B4:     C4: 2
A5: 5   B5:     C5: 0

Type the following formula in cell B1:
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A1,$C$1:$C$5,0)),"",A1)
Select cells B1:B5.
In Microsoft Office Excel 2003 and in earlier versions of Excel, point to Fill on the Edit menu, and then click Down.
In Microsoft Office Excel 2007 and Excel 2010, click Fill in the Editing group, and then click Down.*

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/213367/how-to-compare-data-in-two-columns-to-find-duplicates-in-excel